# Reviews and E-A-T: 3rd party aggregators vs. self managing vs other options?

Tags: seo, html, user-reviews

One of my clients is a hotel chain and I've recently recommended to implement reviews from their customers in their hotels' landing pages. The developer I work with usually picks the (good) reviews from other websites such us Booking and does a manual copy/paste on his clients' websites.

For E-A-T, since Google more and more values the source of the displayed information, is this self-managing system OK for SEO? I don't think it will be *bad*, but I believe other options -where Google can see where the review comes from and therefore be sure that it is a real customer's opinion- would be better.

I've read that GMB had an “embed post” option where the HTML code was provided but this option seems to have disappeared. Do you have any suggestions on how to implement reviews while adding E-A-T and not using any plugins? I'm not sure the client will be willing to pay for it.

Comment: I work for Tripddvisor and I know we offer several widgets for hotels to show ratings and review snippets from on their website: https://www.tripadvisor.com/Widgets

Comment: Thank you, I had already found them but I'd like to consider alternative options.